# Image Not Found in Command with Etoolbox

Tags: graphics, etoolbox

I'm having problems compiling the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\newInfo}[3][]{%
\edef\@creatingInfo{1}%
\edef\@printingInfo{0}%
\edef\currentname{#2}%
\ifstrempty{#1}{}{\csedef{info#2Img}{#1}}%
\csedef{info#2Cnt}{#3}%
\nullfont#3\normalfont%
\edef\@creatingInfo{0}
}

\newcommand{\printInfo}[1]{%
\edef\currentname{#1}%
\edef\@printingInfo{1}%
\section{#1}\label{info:#1}%
\ifcsname info#1Img\endcsname%
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\csuse{info#1Img}}
\end{figure}%
\fi%
\csuse{info#1Cnt}%
\ifcsname info#1Ref\endcsname
\begin{longtable}{p{9cm}}
  \csuse{info#1Ref}
\end{longtable}
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\newInfo[./images/myimage.eps]{Test}{Information content}

\printInfo{Test}


\end{document}
```

It says `./images/myimage.eps not found` (regardless of the name, type, absolute/relative path, etc).

If you, however, replace line 21 by `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./images/myimage.eps}`, then it displays the image correctly.

Comment: Remove the file extension, i.e. use it as  `./images/myimage`

Comment: You should expand `\csuse{info#1Img}` before executing `\includegraphics`. But I can't understand several parts of the code which appear to do nothing useful at all. In particular, what's the purpose of `\nullfont#3\normalfont`?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the automatic conversion from EPS to PDF the file name in the argument to `\includegraphics` should be explicit, so you can change the code into

```
  \ifcsname info#1Img\endcsname
    \begin{figure}
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\csuse{info#1Img}}%
    }\x
    \end{figure}
  \fi
```

Some comments: your example code misses `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, because you want to define commands with `@` in their name. By the way `\edef\@creatingInfo{1}` is exactly the same as `\def\@creatingInfo{1}`, just less efficient.

Moreover, several parts of the code seem to do nothing at all, probably because the shown code is just an excerpt. But

```
\nullfont#3\normalfont
```

is something I can't understand at all. Why typesetting the file name in `\nullfont`, so nothing appears?

Finally, never use the `pdftex` option for `graphicx`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
the \nullfont#3\normalfont is essential for my package. It forces latex to evaluate several commands (which are stored inside other commands) without printing the output. That's why there is the distinction between \@creatingInfo and \@printingInfo